# How to automatically paste the one time code which is received in SMS in react-native text input

Tags: react-native, textinput

I am using Textinput from react-native. How can I paste the otp or code automatcally in the textinput box.

Answer (score 7):

As of react native version 0.66+

Android: Can use the [autocomplete](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#autocomplete-android) set to `sms-otp`

iOS: Can use [textContentType](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#textcontenttype-ios) set to `oneTimeCode`

Answer (score 2):

To paste otp automatically from sms in your iOS app in react-native you need to do following steps:

1. Set textContentType="oneTimeCode"(supported only for iOS devices):

2. You need to Send sms with the following pattern: <#> code: your otp here.

for e.g we send an sms in your company like this: <#> code: 1234.

P.S. I also have autoFocus = {true} on my otp input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "oneTimeCode"

For example:

```
<TextInput style={TEXTHEADER} textContentType="oneTimeCode" />
```

Online reference:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#textcontenttype

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is looking for how to do this in React Native web in a mobile browser, you do not need textContentType since this is an iOS only prop. You can do it by simply auto focusing your input. The code will autofill to whatever input is focused when the user taps on the code.

```
   <TextInput
     autoFocus={true}
     value={value}
     caretHidden={true}
     onChangeText={onChangeText}
     keyboardType="number-pad"
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `textContentType="oneTimeCode"` and `keyboardType="numeric"` on your `TextInput`. [EDIT 2023-01-22] some people (@TaiyrBegeyev) says that it's `keyboardType="number-pad"` instead, I couldn't try it again so... your move !

If you need to handle the code, also add a `onChangeText` prop to the TextInput

and FINALLY, the most important, if you don't see iOS poping up your code coming from SMS, check which message you're sending.
In my case, in French,

- `Veuillez saisir le code ${code} dans l'application` is working
- `Veuillez entrer ce code dans l'application : ${code}` is NOT working

I've been checking RN side for hours, and finally changing the SMS was the solution.

Comment: It works for me when I use `textContentType="oneTimeCode"`, but does not work when I add `keyboardType="numeric"`.

Comment: @MikeyE the `keyboardType` field should be `number-pad` instead.

Comment: I trust you @TaiyrBegeyev I update my answer

Comment: Why OTP should only be numeric ? There is a spec about it ? (In my firm we use alphanumeric otp)

Comment: you're right! I should try with alphanumeric, never tested yet

Answer (score 0):

create new route and paste this code and try it after u send the verification code it will autofill the otp

```
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  Keyboard,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  View,
} from "react-native";
const Contacts = () => {
  const [value, onChangeText] = useState("");
  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onPress={() => {
        Keyboard.dismiss();
      }}
    >
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <TextInput
          // autoFocus={true}
          value={value}
          onChangeText={onChangeText}
          keyboardType="number-pad"
        />
        <Text>contacts</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
};
export default Contacts;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -5):

Easiest way is to use SMS listening built in packages.

[https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-sms-listener](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-otp-verify)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-otp-verify

If you're using react-native-android-SMS-listner package, you can use a code as follows.

```
let subscription = SmsListener.addListener(message => {
  let verificationCodeRegex = /Your verification code: ([\d]{6})/

  if (verificationCodeRegex.test(message.body)) {
    let verificationCode = message.body.match(verificationCodeRegex)[1]

    YourPhoneVerificationApi.verifyPhoneNumber(
      message.originatingAddress,
      verificationCode
    ).then(verifiedSuccessfully => {
      if (verifiedSuccessfully) {
        subscription.remove()
        return
      }

      if (__DEV__) {
        console.info(
          'Failed to verify phone `%s` using code `%s`',
          message.originatingAddress,
          verificationCode
        )
      }
    })
  }
})
```

If youre using react-native-otp-verify you can follow the following tutorial

https://tech.goibibo.com/building-otp-verification-component-in-react-native-with-auto-read-from-sms-2a9a400015b0

Hope this helps