# How to automaticaly pass code from SMS (OTP) on React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I assume that automatically transferring OTP code from SMS with the help of Reactjs instruments is not real.
But maybe someone knows about possibilities?

I know how to pass code inside apple keyboard `intut autoComplete="one-time-code"`. How can i do it for android (`gboard`)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are building a mobile application using React native, in this case, you can find a bunch of libraries that can do the work for you.
Take a look at [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-otp-auto-fill) and search google for "autofill OTP code in react native" for more results.

Comment: No, i need information about React - not react native

Comment: @ЕгорДовыденко I believe you might wanna edit your question, because it mentions React Native.

Answer (score 0):

As of react native version 0.66+

Android: Can use the autocomplete set to sms-otp

iOS: Can use textContentType set to oneTimeCode

the question was already answered here -
[How to automatically paste the one time code which is received in SMS in react-native text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61230843/how-to-automatically-paste-the-one-time-code-which-is-received-in-sms-in-react-n)